# Spanish translation of the idiom "Reaching out to you"

Tags: traducción

I'm attempting to translate the idiom "Reaching out to you" to Spanish.  It's informal, but still used in a business sense such as "I'm reaching out to you again about the message I sent you."  Is there a Spanish equivalent expression?  All I can think of is:

> **contactando a ti**

which doesn't seem to be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

> Te escribo para preguntarte por [...] / Le escribo para [...]

note, a Spanish speaker would not say *contactando a ti* but

> contactarte / contactarle

like

> Quería contactarte para preguntarte acerca del correo que te escribi hace poco [...]

Comment: very helpful.  I assume you didn't mean to write "contactarte" twice though?

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that. I wanted to use tu / usted, because I wasn't sure how you would want to address the addressee on you email. is either contactarTE or contactarLE.

Comment: Also if you're going formal, using *ponerse en contacto con X* might sound a bit better than *contactarle a X* (at least to my ears, YMMV)

Comment: to reach out is not contact someone  and also not write to someone. It actually has a specific meaning....

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren estas dos alternativas que son prácticamente idénticas:

Me pongo en contacto con usted acerca del mensaje que le mandé...

Me pongo en contacto con usted sobre el mensaje que le mandé...

Answer (score 0):

**Extender la mano**

This literally means to reach out one's hand.  But it is used in a figurative sense as well, where it means reaching out through communication.

For examples of usage, both literal and figurative,  you can [follow the link](https://www.spanishdict.com/ejemplos/extender%20la%20mano).

Answer (score 0):

In English, reach out means:

**Definition of reach out
: **to make an effort to do something for other people**
The church is reaching out to help the poor.
**
From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary.

The best fit here in Spanish is **recurrir**:

From the Real Academia:

2. intr. **Acogerse en caso de necesidad al favor de alguien**, o emplear medios no comunes para el logro de un objeto.

[**recurrir** in the RAE](https://dle.rae.es/recurrir)

[reach out in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reach%20out#:~:text=Definition%20of%20reach%20out,out%20to%20help%20the%20poor).

- reach out has colloquially come to mean: to ask for help, also.
- pedir ayuda

There is a slightly different meaning in British English, not really relevant here:

in the Collins Dictionary: to attempt to establish friendly or sympathetic relations (with someone).

But in the specific context here, of reach out **again**, it could also be expressed as:

- **Vuelvo a contactor con usted** etc. o **Vuelvo a pedir su ayuda o apoyo**